# Dropbox running from the desktop uses wrong permissions

Tags: 14.04, permissions, dropbox

I have Dropbox installed on Ubuntu. I launch it from the Dropbox desktop icon. This in turn runs the command "dropbox start -i" to start Dropbox.

- When I create a file the group gets permission "rw" which is correct.
- When Dropbox creates exactly the same file in the same location it creates it with group permission "r" which is not correct.

I am fairy certain that my facl setting, folder permissions and file/folder ownership's are correct but Dropbox seems to be ignoring these.

I have just found out that the desktop icon that I use to launch Dropbox has a "Permissions" tab under properties ("right click"->properties). The group permission here was set to "read-only" so I changed it to "read and write". I then closed Dropbox and restarted it using the desktop icon but it still creates files with group permission "r".

I have looked at lots of posts with similar issues but nothing seems to work for me. A lot of the posts are also very old (2012 ish) and don't seem to relate directly to the latest install of Dropbox on Ubuntu.

Can anyone work out what I need to change to get Dropbox to create files with group permission "rw"? I am pretty sure that it has to be the Dropbox process that has the wrong permissions but I can't work out how or what to change. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a day tyring to work this out I realised that I needed to use setfacl at the Dropbox folder level rather than for some sub folders for this to work. It seems that when users creates files then the correct file permissions are set, but when Dropbox created file in the same folder the permissions were not correctly set. The command that I used was something like this:

sudo setfacl -Rdm g:user:wrx ~/Dropbox